# How can i save the screen as an image from a .NET forms application in C#

Tags: .net-3.5, screen-scraping

I have a .NET 3.5 Windows forms application. When the user keys in data and clicks 'Save', i want to save the entire form as an image file.

How can i do this ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080069/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-send-by-email-programaticly-on-dotnet/1080134#1080134). It shows how to take a screenshot of the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bitmap in size of your screen (System.Windows.Forms.Screen class), create a System.Drawing.Graphics object for it (Graphics.FromImage) and then use Graphics.CopyFromScreen.

You may ve also able to use Form.DrawToBitmap.