# Map a button to do a screenshot then open composetask to send via email wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

ok so i want to screen capture the layout for an app im working on i would like to set screen capture to a button or applicationbar item and after capture go directly into email with that screen shot to send off

i seen here : [How to take a screenshot and send by email programaticly on dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080069/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-send-by-email-programaticly-on-dotnet)

and here: [C# Take ScreenShot of .net control within application and attach to Outlook Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000603/c-sharp-take-screenshot-of-net-control-within-application-and-attach-to-outlook?rq=1)

but im not sure it applies to windows phone 8. I know you can take a screenshot via home button and power button but i would like this done in one swoop if possible

i intially was going to have textboxes filled out and them have an email generated looking somehting like this

```
 private void email_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

        string first = infoBox1.Text;
        string second = infoBox2.Text;
        string third = infoBox3.Text;
        string fourth = infoBox4.Text;

        string one = amountBox1.Text;
        string two = amountBox2.Text;
        string three = amountBox3.Text;
        string four = amountBox4.Text;

        emailComposeTask.To = "";


        emailComposeTask.Body =    

            first + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " +  one + Environment.NewLine +
            second + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + two + Environment.NewLine +
            third + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " +  three + Environment.NewLine +
            fourth + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + four + Environment.NewLine;
```

but i didnt like the output of it, wasnt properly aligned etc...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this code on click of button..

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = String.Format("WmDev_{0:}.jpg", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(LayoutRoot, new MatrixTransform());
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();
        SaveToMediaLibrary(bmpCurrentScreenImage, fileName, 100);
        MessageBox.Show("Captured image " + fileName + " Saved Sucessfully", "WmDev Capture Screen", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        string currentFileName = fileName;
    }
```

then after use this code to save image on camera roll..

```
public void SaveToMediaLibrary(WriteableBitmap bitmap, string name, int quality)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.
            bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);
        }
    }
```

now you can check in your camera roll the screen captured will be saved.
Make sure once check on your WMAppManifest.xml and in capability you check-mark on all capability then run your code I am sure it will work

Comment: man thank for sticking it out with me the WMAppManifest.xml was the key thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For taking screen-shots you can follow this link..

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/index.php?title=How_to_take_screenshot_on_Windows_Phone&ampdiff=176659&ampoldid=175825

and there is no way still in Windows phone 8 SDK to send email via EmailTask with an attachment.

Comment: thanks for the reference, i was actually looking for something more refined way i mean phones like the nokia 920 have this option as native so isnt there a more simple to call a screenshot and map it to a button or something?.

Comment: I think you want to call screen-shots on click of button?

Comment: yessiirr i do like putting a camera button on page or on application bar that takes the screen shot

Comment: ok well so you can use this code:----http://pastie.org/7747288 I posted my code here you can use where you need.or download (Code Example
Source file: Media:WmDev CaptureScreen.zip) form http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_capture_screen_programmatically_in_Windows_Phone_7

Comment: ok inserted your code and over look link you sent..when pressing the applicationbarbutton  UnauthorizedAccessException is throw and stops there..sorry still learning more and more

Comment: But my proposal is you can download sample code and check it..I think you missed some piece of code.please for more reference download the Zip file given in above link.

Comment: ok yea i only use the piece that you post in pastie ill check the sample code

Comment: the exception happens on this line of code......................... new  MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);

Comment: Make sure once check on your WMAppManifest.xml and in capability you check-mark on all capability then run your code I am sure it will work.