# Save here maps screenshot in isolated storage on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, nokia

I want to generate a screenshot of an map control on Windows Phone 8 and save this image to isolated storage. Does anybody have a small piece of code which would do this? I've tried to generate a WriteableBitmap out of the map control, but this image is only black.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292973/map-a-button-to-do-a-screenshot-then-open-composetask-to-send-via-email-wp8)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just what you are looking for see [SaveMapImageEx](https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples/tree/master/SaveMapImageEx) from the samples I have made (with my friends) and stored at [nokia-developer/maps-samples](https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples) at GitHub.