# How can I edit the below C# code to attach the screenshot in the present email Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, screenshot, attachment

I am using C# MVC Architecture.

**Brief Introduction about the function that I have implemented.**

A Recruiter can post job adverts by logging into their accounts.Once a job is posted,that particular job will be listed under pending confirmation.An admin can view the confirmation pending job adverts from the admin panel.They can view it and either accept it or reject it or edit and accept it.So when an admin accepts the job advert,that particular job advert will go live in the website.And also an email will be sent to that particular recruiter indicating that their job vacancy has been published on the website along with the link.

So when a recruiter is posting a job advert,they can include the basic job details and also there is a feature that they can add screening questions for applicants to answer when they submit their CV.So when an admin is checking for confirmation pending jobs adverts ,they view these screening questions and sometimes they edit some questions and accept the advert.

**Problem**

Along with the email sent when an admin accepts the job advert,I want to add a screenshot of the screening questions.As an admin is getting so many job adverts,sending an email manually is difficult.

i want to attach the Screenshot of the screening questions as well.

**I referred.**

[Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

And

[How to take a screenshot and send by email programaticly on dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080069/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-send-by-email-programaticly-on-dotnet)

Iam finding it difficult to combine it to my implementation.How can I add this to my existing Code?To which classes do I have to add and do the amendments,

I tried but had no success.

And what are the libraries that I have to import?

Any help is appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: Images in emails are a nuisance for various reaosns; is there any way you can alter the spec to show the screening questions as text, not an image?

Comment: The screening questions stored aren't stored in db? well eitherway you could still access their answers once they post on your action right?

Comment: Both your links are desktop code and your code is asp.net-mvc code, so it wont work. The web server has no access to the client primary sreen

Comment: This type of question is off topic, screenshot is not a good fit anyway. Usually we would trace the questions and the form content in a database, or a file format, all of the information is posted from the server to the backend as data, you replay the data in a similar view for recipients to see. There are many other flavours to this too, screenshot is the least effective solution even in a desktop setting, we only use screenshots in error handling but even then it is a poor solution for a poorly designed process. You can even make them work in JavaScript, but it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Yes the screening questions and the expected answers are stored in 2 different tables in the database.Iam using Sql Server.The questions may differ depending on the type of the job advert.Once an admin accepts the job advert ,the questions and the answers will be stored in the db.

Comment: @Cleptus You mean that I cannot accomplish this task using asp.net mvc ?

Comment: Not with the link of those links, very likely doable with some client side scripting (probably some javascript I am not aware of). The easiest way would be either WPF or winforms imho.

Comment: @Cleptus Thankyou So Much.i am using jquey and c# in my project and I am unawre of WPF and winforms imho.Let me look into those

Comment: @rissa any reason why you don't want to put the texts of their answers instead? The screenshot will just contain the questions and answers-- why not mail them the questions and answers since they're already in the database?

Comment: you could format the email to look like a web page too